# Setting a specific value in a DataTable + writing on DB - C#

Tags: c#

The steps of my program are:

1. Read a CSV file
2. Read, from a DB, the ID from a specific file name (from step 1)
3. Create a DataTable with the CSV file
4. Add a column with the ID from step 2
5. Write the result on a DB

My problem:

- The ID is not being written on the DB

The code has several parts. I will paste the main ones:

1. Calls:

   ```
               string id_file = Get_id_file(filenameout, id_costumer);
               //MessageBox.Show("the id of the file will be: " + id_file);


               DataTable csvFileData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(filenameout, id_file);

               InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(csvFileData, destinytablename);
   ```
2. Reading from the DB:

   ```
       public static string Get_id_file(string filenameout,string id_id_costumer)
   {

       var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filenameout);
       string return_id_file = "";

       using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("XXXXX"))
       {
           try
           {
               dbConnection.Open();
               SqlDataReader myReader = null;

               // Using the DB to find the value
               SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select ID from TB_FILE_NAMES where path_name='" + fileName + "' and id_program='" + id_id_costumer + "'",
                                                        dbConnection);
               myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

               while (myReader.Read())
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("the ID selected for the file is: " + myReader["ID"].ToString());
                   return_id_file = (myReader["ID"].ToString());

               }

               //return_id_file = "9999";
               return return_id_file;

           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
               return ("Error in return_id_file");
           }


       } // end of using (SqlConnection dbConnection)
   }
   ```
3. Part of "GetDataTableFromCSVFile"
   On this part, I just wanna set the ID (found in the previous step) to all rows for that specific CSV

   ```
           // Add a column with the ID of the file
       //DataColumn Col = 
       csvData.Columns.Add("ID_TB_FILE_NAMES", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

       // Set a value for the entire column - ID of the File
       //var column2 = csvData.Columns["ID_TB_FILE_NAMES"];

       foreach (DataRow row in csvData.Rows)
       {
           //row.SetField(id_file_name, column2);
           row.SetField("ID_TB_FILE_NAMES", id_file_name);
       }

       return csvData;

   } // end of GetDataTabletFromCSVFile
   ```
4. Writing, on the DB, the csvData:

   ```
      static void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(DataTable csvFileData,string destinytablename)
   {


       using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("XXXXX"))
       {

           dbConnection.Open();

           // Clean the destiny table
           //string query = "TRUNCATE TABLE " + destinytablename;
           //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnection);
           //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


           using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
           {
               s.DestinationTableName = destinytablename;
               //foreach (var column in csvFileData.Columns)
               //    s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
               s.WriteToServer(csvFileData);
           }
       }


   } // end of InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy
   ```

I spent 3 days trying to figure out... Any help is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: The other columns are inserting fine, just not the column you added? Also, what is the datatype (in the destination table) of the column you're trying to add?

Comment: Two things to check 1) Does the CSV file date stamp get updated when you run code? 2)  Add break point on the line SQlBulkCopy (F9).  Then right click on csvFileData and sedlect "Add To Watch".   The hover to down arrow and select DataTableVisualizer.  See if the new column contains data.

Comment: Hey @Cory
All the columns are inserting fine, just the ID (the one that I am manipulating) that is always empty;
With datatype, do you mean the table that is it in the DB? If yes, "varchar(50)";

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. Is the data you're trying to insert larger than 50 characters? SqlBulkCopy is notorious for swallowing errors.

Comment: I discovered the problem!
After Cory asked about the type of field in the DB I noticed that I had one extra field in the middle of the mess. On DB, I had an automatic ID creation field which was before the field that I need to fill with the information from the CSV;

After I change the order of the fields in the DB, I was able to run + the ID is being saved on the DB.

Also, @jdweng, I discovered this using your idea of "DataTableVisualizer" - really really helpful!

Thank you Cory and jdweng!